# Search bar broke

Tags: windows-search, debug, cortana, bug-tracking

**Note:** This is similar to another question here but I have made a new one for getting solutions for thr curre t Windows version. Also I have tried a lot of troubleshooting steps. So I thought asking a new question will be better. Please don't mark this as duplicate.

So I followed this page recently: [A post to remove Cortana completely](https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-uninstall-and-remove-cortana-in-windows-10/). It worked but the side effects were pretty bad. The search won't open when clicked and even hard reset isn't fixing it. I have already tried re-registering Cortana with a reboot but it doesn't work.

Comment: Cortana is integrated with search bar. If you remove Cortana the search bar won't work.

Answer (score 1):

That's what the caution said in this guide you mentioned:

> Caution: Uninstalling Cortana breaks the Windows 10 Start Menu and
>   probably Search so don't use this if you use the native menu.  You
>   will not be able to get it working back easily. You will not be able
>   to-reinstall it quickly without using the genuine install.wim file.
>   For most users, this means that Cortana will be removed from Windows
>   10 permanently.

At this time, we can just try In-place upgrade to repair Cortana components:

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html

Comment: Just to confirm, this means I need to get an ISO file which is the same version and language as my current Windows, and use that ISO file, to, like, fill up the missing files and repair the broken sections in my PC, right?